# Where condition with multiple result set on ZF2 AbstractTableGateway

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

In Zf2 application written the model file to retrieve the data set from the table,
it works as expected for returning one result set, but for returning multiple rows not able to achieve by the below code.

> Working and Returning single row

```
/**
     * @param $id
     * @return bool|Entity\Feeds
     */
    public function getAppFeed($id)
    {
        $row = $this->select(array('app_id' => (int)$id))->current();
        if (!$row)
            return false;
        $feedVal = new Entity\Feeds(array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'title' => $row->title,
            'link' => $row->link,
            'Description' => $row->description,
            'created' => $row->created,
        ));
        return $feedVal;

    }
```

Removed current and tried tablegateway object also but throwing the error.

Feeds table will have multiple record for each of the application, I need a function to achieve the same.

Comment: What is the exact error when removing *->current()* ?

Comment: not getting any error, table has multiple rows of data for the app_id i have to get all the rows from the query.  current returns only one result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` always returns a `ResultSet`. You can access the objects(1) of ResultSet by iterating over it, because it implements the `Iterator` Interface.

Just an example piece of code:

```
public function getAppFeed($id)
{
    $resultSet = $this->select(array('app_id' => (int)$id));

    if ($resultSet instanceof \Zend\Db\ResultSet) {
        foreach($resultSet as $item) {
            // do your feed stuff here
            // e.g. $item->id
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(1) Object: meaning whatever object you asigned as `Prototype` in your `TableGateway`.

For further details, please checkout the documentation of [ResultSet](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html).